# Bitcoin testnet not connecting to hardcoded ip addresses

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, testnet, testing, peer-discovery

I am trying to force `bitcoind` running in `testnet mode` to connect to my own defined set of ip addresses(basically 127.0.0.1:diffPorts). For this I have disabled dnsseed and starting with a fresh installation of `bitcoind`.

Currently I am trying to simulate 4 nodes on a local machine, such that all 4 are hardcoded into the `chainparamseeds` file as follows:

```
static SeedSpec6 pnSeed6_test[] = {
    {{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xff,0x7f,0x00,0x00,0x01}, 18441},
    {{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xff,0x7f,0x00,0x00,0x01}, 18442},
    {{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xff,0x7f,0x00,0x00,0x01}, 18443},
    {{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xff,0x7f,0x00,0x00,0x01}, 18444}
};
```

My `debug.log` output ends as follows:

```
2015-10-22 11:53:43 Loading addresses from DNS seeds (could take a while)
2015-10-22 11:53:43 net thread start
2015-10-22 11:53:43 0 addresses found from DNS seeds
2015-10-22 11:53:43 init message: Done loading
2015-10-22 11:53:43 addcon thread start
2015-10-22 11:53:43 dnsseed thread exit
2015-10-22 11:53:43 opencon thread start
2015-10-22 11:53:43 msghand thread start
2015-10-22 11:54:44 Adding fixed seed nodes as DNS doesn't seem to be available.
```

I expect the nodes should have connected to each other after the last line indicates that fixed seeds have been added, but that does not happens. Can someone guide me what am I missing here ?

Comment: You're probably better off using `addnode` or `connect` command line arguments to do this sort of thing rather than modifying the binary. Probably better off using `regtest` as well if you just want a private testing network, it's a lot more suited for the job.

Answer (score 1):

These are seed nodes, not nodes that are connected to for a connection. A seed node means that it is a node that will be connected to in order to get addresses of other nodes to connect to. That connection will not be maintained; rather it is temporary.

If you want to connect nodes to each other, you should not be modifying the seed nodes at all. Rather you should be using the `-connect=<ip>` option (or add it to your bitcoin.conf file) to connect only specific nodes.